# Only perform search when IP Address is available

Tags: ios, filemaker

I try to script in Filemaker that some tasks only would be done if an IP address (not in current subnet) is available.

*FYI: that check would be done on an iPad/iPhone FM Go, which might (or night not) have Internet connection.*

What would be a known good way to do this?

Best regards

Comment: Any computer with a network card (even if not connected) has an IP address available ([127.0.0.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)) so please clarify what do you exactly need.

Comment: Ping it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)

Comment: What services does the remote computer have turned on? If it is a web server, you could possibly do something Filemaker-native with a scripted webview and inspection of the resulting HTML. If not, you could use a plugin to run Ping or some other command to see if the remote IP address can be reached.

Comment: Thank you for those 3 comments. I specified, that this should be used on Go Versions of FileMaker. Thus, there always is a network card, no native ping function (or is there?) and no plugin support.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "IP address is available". What exactly makes it "available"? IOW, what do you want to do if the answer is yes?

Comment: there is a server running on the computer with that IP Address and a local database will work with it

Comment: So start "working with it" and trap for error? -- P.S. Being laconic is not a good policy when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is your scenario:

- You have a FileMaker GO file that is being run locally from the iOS device (locally meaning the file is actually on the iOS device and not being accessed remotely)
- You have some tasks that you want to do in a remote FileMaker file hosted on a FileMaker Server, but you want to be sure your GO file can actually communicate with the server before trying to accomplish any of the tasks
- You know that your iOS device could have a network connection but still not be able to "see" the FileMaker file that's hosted on the FileMaker Server

Assuming that this is correct, you could add the server file as an External Data Source for your iOS file via `File->Manage->External Data Sources`. You could write a small script that check's for a record from that external data source before proceeding with your tasks. e.g.

```
# Script: check if remote file is available
If [ not IsEmpty(RemoteTable::ID) ] 
    Exit Script [true]
End If
Exit Script [false]
```

This script assumes that you have a table in your remote file (in this example `RemoteTable`) that:

- Has an `ID` field that is ALWAYS populated (e.g. a serial number value or a calculation with a hard coded value)
- Your iOS file has the table occurrence `RemoteTable` added to it's relationship graph